# How to send an email from elgg to an external email account user@yahoo.com

Tags: elgg

I've trying to send an email from [elgg](https://www.elgg.org/) to `user@yahoo.com`, but nothing really happens. This is my actions file:

Rev/actions/Rev/room_reservation.php

```
function confirm_reservation() {
    elgg_send_email("user@gmail.com", "user@yahoo.com", 'Reserved', 'Good Message', null);

    forward('reportedcontent/add');
}
```

I've even tried:

Rev/actions/Rev/room_reservation.php

```
function emailConfirmation() {
    $to      = 'user@yahoo.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: user@yahoo.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

The start.php:

```
elgg_register_action('Rev/reservation', "$base/Rev/reservation.php");
```

Whare am I going wrong? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to put the confirm_reservation() function in your action file. Look the codes of some of the bundled plugins and you will be able to understood it better.

Also make sure your php is able to send mails.